# Joda DateTimeFormatter Exception thrown when setting the time zone: "is malformed at"

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, date-formatting

I'm trying to use the Joda library's DateTimeFormatter to parse a DateTime object from a String. For some reason it is throwing an exception when it reaches the time zone to parse.

Here is my code:

```
    protected static final String DEFAULT_TIMEZONE = "America/Denver";
    // Parse the date for the note
    DateTimeFormatter dtFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a ZZZ");
    String dateStr = defaultMonth + "/15/" + defaultYear + " 12:00 am " + DateTimeZone.forID(DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);
    try {
        DateTime noteDate = dtFormatter.parseDateTime(dateStr);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

StackTrace:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "11/15/2014 12:00 am America/Denver" is malformed at "America/Denver"
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:683)
>       at com.happyjacksoftware.emr.actions.AddreportnotesController.create(AddreportnotesController.java:56)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

I don't actually take in any time as an input, so I was trying the pattern string `"MM/dd/yyyy ZZZ"`but this did not work, and I thought maybe the DateTime object needed a time to be instantiated. Adding the time however did not work.

*NOTE*: I did try this with the pattern string `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a Z"` and string `11/15/2014 12:00 am -0700` and it worked, but getting the numeric offset is much less convenient for me, so I was hoping there is a solution to use the Timezone ID.

Comment: `DateTime noteDate = dtFormatter.parseDateTime("11/15/2014 12:00 am America/Denver");` works fine for me. Can you try to run that specific line of code?

Comment: Hmmm, yeah even trying to parse with the "hardcoded" string you posted above still yields the same exception message: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "11/15/2014 12:00 am America/Denver" is malformed at "America/Denver".` I cleaned the server thinking maybe the Joda library got out of whack, but it didn't help.

Comment: @PopoFibo - yes ZZZ means ZoneID

Comment: @JakubK Yes, was just confirming OP had it consistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've checked your code on JodaTime 2.1 - 2.3 and it's working properly. I think that you use some old version which can behave in different way. In current versions of Joda parseDateTime method starts at line 841 and your stacktrace shows error in line 683. Timezones database is different and that's because your're getting parse exception.

Comment: [Works for me](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid) are not really answers but comments. Also use comment if you want to ask OP question. Answers are for solutions, not questions.

Comment: It's answer - problem is that he uses old version of JodaTime

Comment: It looks I'm using JodaTime 1.6.2. I didn't realize it was so old...I'll see if using a newer version helps (Although I was able to do this in a different project without having this problem)

Comment: Yes - look at the stacktrace

Comment: @rawkfist0215 you can find more details about timezeones database here: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/tz_update.html

Comment: @JakubK +1 after OP confirmed your suspicions. No hard fillings, just it seemed more like hunch rather then actual answer before your edit.

Comment: Yup, updating to the latest version did solve the problems. Thanks @JakubK for the helpful link, and thanks to both of you for your time.